# Using Htaccess to Remove Part Of The URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to remove the /design/ from this URL (and any that contain it).

```
https://www.domain.com/design/subcategory/productname1
```

At the end, I want it to look like this:

```
https://www.domain.com/subcategory/productname1
```

But since that would obvious cause a 404 of you just deleted that part of the URL, I need to populate that second URL with the contents of the first. I apologize if I am not using the correct terms but here is an example of something similar I have on my site.

In my header menu, I have a link that indicates it will take you here:

```
https://www.domain.com/index.php?route=product/search&tag=shirts
```

But I wanted it to look like this:

```
https://www.domain.com/shirts/
```

So I researched it and this solution worked great:

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product/search/\?tag=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L,NE]
# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ product/search/?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can something similar be done to remove the /design/ part of the URL?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is correct, the subcategory is the part that will change. Its for types of designs so there wlll a subcategory called "nerd", "gaming", etc.

Comment: But you don't want `/design/` to be added to `/product/search?tag=...` URI so it is important to know list of URIs where `/design/` is going to be added or list of URIs where `/design/`won't be added.

Comment: I don't want /design/ in the URL anywhere. Here are the places where it is currently found: 

domain.com/design/abstract/
domain.com/design/animals/
domain.com/design/characters/

etc.

Comment: If I add a product, it goes into one of them (e.g. domain.com/design/abstract/product1). I don't want that parent category in the URL at all (/design/), can it be removed and the contents proxied using htaccess?

Comment: And just to clarify, /design/ will never be added, Here are all my categories:

`https://www.domain.com/design/abstract/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/animals/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/characters/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/games/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/geek-nerd/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/graphic/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/keep-calm/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/movies-tv/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/pop-culture/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/skulls-bones/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/tattoo/`
`https://www.domain.com/design/typography/`

Comment: ok what are you current URIs that don't start with `/design/`?

Comment: Here are most of them, all the products will unfortunately have the /design/ in them because all products will be part of a subcategory (whose parent category is "design" - http://pastebin.com/0kLg0TW7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove /design/ from URLs and redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+design/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# internally add design/ to know set of URIs
RewriteRule ^(skulls-bones|characters|abstract|animals|games|geek-nerd|graphic|keep-calm|movies-tv|pop-culture|tattoo|typography)(/.*)?$ design/$1$2 [L,NC]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product/search/\?tag=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/design/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ product/search/?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Worked! I made a slight adjustment to the "add design/ to known set of URLs but otherwise everything is 100%. Thanks so much! Here is the pastebin for anyone else that needs it. The names listed there are my categories - http://pastebin.com/Ra9ZF7KQ

Comment: That's great to know. I have updated those rules in my answer.

Comment: I have noticed an error. Any category that contains a "-" doesn't work (for example, "skulls-bones" or "geek-nerd"). However, anything with a single word works fine (e.g. "animals" or "games". Any idea why that is happening? How does htaccess view the "-"? Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing specific to hyphen in these rules. What's the full URL you entered in browser and what error do you get?